# How can I avoid Outlook to change in my meeting time automatically from *:00 to *:05 in the Microsoft Outlook web interface (OWA)?

Tags: outlook.com, calendar

Demonstration of the issue: the default time is 1:05 when I first open the new calendar window. I then select 1:00 as my meeting start time in my Microsoft Outlook web interface (OWA)'s calendar, and Outlook automatically changes my meeting start time to 1:05.

[image]

I use Outlook/Office 365 via my employer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reddit user [ccatlett1984](https://www.reddit.com/user/ccatlett1984) [told me](https://redd.it/p0t0o5) this can be changed in the settings: https://outlook.office.com/mail/options/calendar/eventAndInvitations:

[image]